# What is the output of a machine learning algorithm?

Tags: input, machine-learning, output

I'm starting to study machine learning. I have a basic knowldege about it. If I consider a generic machine learning algorithm M, I would know which are its precise inputs and outputs. I'm not referring to some kind of implementation in a such programming language. I'm talking about the theory of machine learning.
Take the example of supervised learning. The input of M should be the collection of pairs  related to the function f the algorithm must learn. So, it will build some function h which approximate f. The output of M should be h?
And what about unsupervised machine learning?

Comment: there is no such thing. ML is broad enough to cover nearly every possible answer.

Comment: This question is too broad for Stackoverflow. I recommend reading some articles on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning#How_supervised_learning_algorithms_work) or similar sites and then ask more specific questions e.g. on the [Cross validated community](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Why is it a broad question? I'm only asking which are input and output of a ML algorithm. And why should I post in Cross validated community? This is not a statistics question.

Comment: @foolcool Your question is a theoretical one. Stackoverflow focuses on specific implementation problems which involve code (which your question doesn't, as you state yourself). Cross validated handles theoretical questions like yours for questions related to statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, and data visualization (according to their [description](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tour)).

Comment: @foolcool Btw, I think you are close to the answer to your question. In general each supervised machine learning algorithm can be trained with a feature matrix `X` and target vector `y` (which corresponds to the pairs you mentioned). The model trained by the algorithm is then the function `h` which should approximate f.

Comment: It's this I would know. Thank you @RobinSpiess

Answer (score 2):

The output of ML algorithms is whatever you want it to be.

For example:

- Regression: 1 value
- Classification: n classes (with the probability of the input is a member of that class)
- Text summarization: One word, one character, a batch of them or the whole text summarized.

As you see, the output will be what you need it to be.